# Two ways to check integrity of container. Which better?

Tags: c, security, hash, data-integrity

There is container which integrity need to be checked and then it need to be parsed:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
|   Obj. count  |  1_Obj.size |  1_Obj. data |  ...  |  N_Obj. size |  N_Obj. data |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It consists from 2N + 1 elements, where:
          -one common header (objects count)
        -N objects. Each object consists from header (object size) and data

To check integrity I hash container with sha256 hash and then compare hash with expected one.

I see two ways how integrity could be checked:
        1. Hashing whole container at once, then compare hash with expected one.  After we could parse container.
        2. Use stream based approach (check integrity and parse simultaneously): each element of container is hashed separately by                       SHA256_Update() routine. Then call SHA256_Final() to get final hash. Using this approach requires        parsing container's internals (common header and each object's headers). But since headers of container could be compromised by an attacker, we couldn't be sure in correctness of data we read  until we finish checking integrity. So looks like this approach could be a security issue.

First approach seems will work slower than second but a bit safe.
Second seems faster but looks like dangerous because we access not verified container's internals.

What anyone also thinks about this? Are there any common rules, techniques or whatever which describes how integrity should be checked in this particular case. Are second approach is dangerous from security point of view? If yes, how we could argument it?

Comment: When you say "each element of container" do you mean hashing `Obj.count` then `1_Obj.size` then `1_Obj.data`, etc? Or do you just mean hashing `1_Obj.data`, `2_Obj.data`, etc? (The former sounds like it would be identical to #1.) As far as a rule: the rule is typically quite simple: never be clever. What problem are you trying to solve by doing anything other than #1? (There is probably a standard solution to that specific problem.)

Comment: You tagged this as `c`, but it's not clear whether there is an actual programming-related question here. It may better belong on security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Rob Napier Hello, Yes, I mean hashing all elements of container. Second approach is exists because seems it should work faster than first. I edited question,  please check.

Comment: When you say "First approach seems will work slower than second," it's unclear how you've implemented this. If you're hashing all the bytes in both cases, then they are identical. I suspect his has to do more with your SHA2 implementation (perhaps its making unnecessary copies?) than with anything inherent to the algorithm. Batch processing with SHA-2 is just implemented by updating many times and then performing the final calculation. Do you have some short code examples that show how 1 and 2 are implemented?